# How to call a controller on a cli application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, command-line-interface

I have a **Console application** (**NET Core 2.2**) and the main function of this application is in the cli. But I want to call a rest api endpoint on it to (to get some informations about this application). Now I implement code into the Program.cs, add a Startup.cs and a controller. But **I can't reach my controller via Postman. What is missing?**

Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    // further logick...
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5002");
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddBusinessComponents();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("cli/v1/dataPicker/info")]
public class InfoController : Controller
{
    private IInfoBusinessComponent BusinessComponent { get; }

    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetInfoAsync()
    {
        Statuses statuses = null;
        try
        {
            statuses = await BusinessComponent.GetInfo();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Exception occurred while trying to get health informations.");
        }

        return Ok(statuses);
    }
}
```

Here my Postman response:
[image: screen shot of postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add lines (launchBrowser and applicationUrl) at the launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "DataPicker.Cli": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Key": "Value",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5003/"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can reach my API through Browser and even Swagger. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class InfoController : Controller
{ 
    [HttpGet("GetInfo")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetInfoAsync()
    {
        Statuses statuses = null;
        try
        {
            statuses = await BusinessComponent.GetInfo();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Exception occurred while trying to get health informations.");
        }

        return Ok(statuses);
    }
}
```

And call it in browser like:

```
http://localhost:5002/api/Info/GetInfo
```

Comment: It's not working. I get the response:

"This site can’t be reached"

Comment: What do you mean? Changing the application type at the properties?

Comment: No. Creating new Api application.

Comment: In .Net Core, we do not have `ApiController`, but @Nenad's answer can solve your issue.

Comment: As I say at the initial problem: My application is mainly a console application and it should stay as a console app, not a web api.

Comment: Ok. I tried this but it does not work as I want. The purpose of the cli is a listener. When I put the listener in the Program.cs of the Api. When the listener is coded before BuildWebHost(args).Build()... than it is listening until the first incoming event, than the Api is starting but the listener not listen anymore. And when I put the listener after BuildWebHost(args).Build()... than I get the Api and the listener never reacts on events. So I'm not getting further.